# I have some raw JSON stored in a variable and just want to post it to an API

Tags: javascript, json

I have been traversing through Stackoverflow and everywhere else on the web to try and find a solution to my issue..
I am working in Javascript and attempting to POST a small section of JSON to an endpoint in the API i know is working (I have completes the GET and POST manually in Postman)

Here is my issue..
I want dont really want to do the "GET" in my programme I just want to either reference the file or even just store it in a little variable.

So for example I have in my code:

```
var OauthUpload = {
"objects": [
    {
        "name": "api",
        "serviceID": 16,
        "properties": {}
    }
],
"version": "integration",
"environment": "redshift"
}
```

Then I am trying to reference this in the JS function:

```
function ApiPostOauth (port) {


$.post(OauthUpload, "http://docker.dc.test.com:" + getActualPort(port) + "/rest/v1/oauth/import", runner);
```

}

But I am having no joy! I have seen a few different silutions but none seem to fit for me.

Basically I want a way to just:

Reference my own JSON as a variable and then insert tht so my function "ApiPostOauth" has that inserted before it runs?

Thanks guys

Steve

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your question. You keep using the term "reference" but I cannot make out what you mean by it each time. Furthermore, what "file" are you talking about? Finally, there is no JSON here (although presumably `$.post` will serialise your object to JSON for transport).

Comment: `OauthUpload` is not "raw JSON". It's a plain JavaScript object. And assuming `$.post()` is the jQuery API (which it may not be, I understand) the first argument is supposed to be a URL, not some random object.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — `$.post` serializes to application/x-www-form-urlencoded not JSON.

Comment: The OauthUpload = {
"objects": [
    {
        "name": "api",
        "serviceID": 16,
        "properties": {}
    }
],
"version": "integration",
"environment": "redshift"
}  is the JSON.
I want the function ApiPostOauth to inherit this and then run the POST?

Comment: @StevieWarbz - It seems you are confusing a JavaScript Object (`OauthUpload` is a JavaScript Object), with a JSON _String_. You see, if `OauthUpload` were really JSON, it would be surrounded by single quotes like this: `'OauthUpload = { "objects": [ { "name": "api", "serviceID": 16, "properties": {} } ], "version": "integration", "environment": "redshift" }'`

Comment: Once you've gotten that straight, the next. thing that you need to correct is the call the $.post(). Assuming jQuery, the `post` method description is: `jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`; You see, the URL is the first parameter and the data ('OauthUpload`) should be second. You have them reversed.

Comment: Hey @RandyCashburn thank you for your help, I appreciate it! So i tried: 

function ApiPostOauth (port) {

    OauthUpload = { "objects": [ { "name": "api", "serviceID": 16, "properties": {} } ], "version": "integration", "environment": "redshift" }


    $.post("http://docker.dc.test.com:" + getActualPort(port) + "/rest/v1/oauth/import", OauthUpload, runner);

Still no joy

Comment: Anyone else got any ideas? Thank you

Comment: @Quentin: You are correct

Comment: @RandyCasburn: The single quotes would not include `OauthUpload = `

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yes, dang it, silly typo. Didn't really matter because the OP didn't understand it anyway. The OP's next example still didn't quote or serialize the object. I think this may be a lost cause. No one is willing to provide an answer.

Comment: @Randy Probably because the question needs to be improved first, per my first comment ;p

Comment: Thank you @RandyCasburn I think i'm almost there thanks to your help...

Have I got this right then...

let url = "http://docker.dc.test.com:9001/rest/v1/oauth/import";
let OauthUpload = {
  objects: [{
    name: "api",
    serviceID: 16,
    properties: {}
  }],
  version: "integration",
  environment: "redshift"
}

ApiPostOauth(OauthUpload);

function ApiPostOauth(data) {
  $.post(url, data, runner)
}

function runner(data) {
  document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
}

I have put the <pre> in the HTML.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together an example for your use. When executing this code, the server will return the same object it is sent. So the 'OauthUpload` object is sent as the request body and the server returns the exact same object. Note: if you don't see output in the output panel when running the sample I will need to restart the server (leave a comment). This is here to demonstrate:

[EDIT] - after re-reading your question, it appears you would like to pass the 'OauthUpload` object into the function. I've updated the example.

You have a mistake in your call to jQuery `post()` method. As shown in the comments, the first two arguments are reversed in the call to `post()`.

Since you didn't pick up on that, I decided to provide an example using your code. Since I don't have your server, I stood up a server for this example. So the URL and port will be different, but the AJAX call will be the same.

Please pay close attention to the `OauthUpload` object. Notice the property names are no longer surrounded by `"`. I removed these quotes because they seemed to be causing you confusion about JavaScript objects and JSON strings (there is no such thing as a JSON Object regardless of what you read on the web - JSON is a string format).

Next, look at the differences between the call made to `$.post()` in my example and your code. You will see the URL comes first in that call.

```js
let url = "//SimpleCORSEnabledServer--randycasburn.repl.co/rest/v1/oauth/import";
let OauthUpload = {
  objects: [{
    name: "api",
    serviceID: 16,
    properties: {}
  }],
  version: "integration",
  environment: "redshift"
}

ApiPostOauth(OauthUpload);

function ApiPostOauth(data) {
  $.post(url, data, runner)
}

function runner(data) {
  document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```